# If statement executing when as far as I can see it shouldn't be - C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
int32 var1 = 81;
double var2 = 2;
if ((var1/10) < (var1 + var2) / 10)
{
    some code to execute;
}
```

As far as my understanding goes, when dividing it removes the remainder so the if statement should be resolving to "if 8 < 8 then execute" and so shouldn't execute but it does, bit stumped here. Is it because I am using different variable types?

I have tried printing the results of (var1/10) and (var1 + var2) / 10 separately and they both output 8 to the console.

Comment: Are you sure? `(var1 + var2) / 10` should be `double`.

Comment: Do you at all have any suspicion about the `double`?

Comment: `(var1 + var2) / 10` is of type double and should evaluate to 8.3.

Comment: Are you sure printing ```(var1 + var2) / 10``` to the console outputs 8 and not 8.3?

Answer (score 8):

> Is it because I am using different variable types?

**Yes that is correct:**

`var1/10` is `8` (integer division)

`(var1 + var2) / 10` is `8.3` (floating point division; `var1` is promoted to a floating point).

In the evaluation of the `if`, `8` is promoted to floating point.

`8.0 < 8.3` is `true`. So the `if` statement executes.

---

> and they both output 8 to the console.

**No they don't.**

Comment: That's what I had a suspicion was happening, though the outputs to console was throwing me. I think I may be outputting with a function that only takes integers or converts or something, will test and update in 30 mins or so. Thanks everyone!!